# Set Audience to Top Link Navigation dynamically

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, top-link-bar, audiences

I am creating Top Link navigation dynamically on feature activation code. I want to audience the navigation so that only authorized user see the relevant navigation items. I know there is property ofSPNavigationItem e.g. item.Properties["Audience"]. But not sure how to set a number of groups and a mix of groups and users.
Please suggest

Comment: Check out the format mentioned here: http://www.sharepointkings.com/2010/02/set-audience-targeting-programmatically.html. Don't know for sure if it's the same, but that would make sense I guess.

Comment: Had you try to use the spsecuritytrimmedcontrol ?